# How to trim extra spaces after the last character in PHP using anyscript

Tags: php

Can u guys help me with a code that eliminates white spaces form the front as well as the back when inserting into my sql back of characters

For Eg: lets say that the word `"   hello   "`. Now i want to remove all these space when i enter my data in MySQL so when it gets inserted there are no more spaces either in the front or back of the word.

Comment: A google search for "php trim extra spaces" has the answer as first result.

Comment: -1. Absolutely no research done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim):

```
$string = '    aaa ';
$string = trim($string);
var_dump($string);
string(3) "aaa"
```

*This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of str.*

Answer (score 5):

The [PHP Trim Function](http://php.net/trim) does exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

Use PHP's [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function.

> trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

```
$string = "   hello   ";
echo trim($string); // "hello"
```

There is also [ltrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) and [rtrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) for trimming only the beginning/end of a string.

---

You also tagged JavaScript so I'll provide a JS resource as well:

[Faster JavaScript Trim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript) has many implementations of trim in JS.

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
};

"   hello   ".trim();  // "hello"
```

Answer (score 4):

With Php you can use an inbuilt function `trim` here is an example :-

```
<?php
    $my_var = '   hello world  ';
    echo $my_var . "\n";  //  hello world  
    $trimmed = trim($my_var);
    echo $trimmed ;       //hello world

?>
```

you can check it [Here](http://codepad.org/F3hdXQY6). The official reference of PHP for the same  [PHP Reference TRIM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP's [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function:

```
$trimmed = trim($text);
```

If you want to do this with JavaScript as well, you can use `.trim()`:

```
> '   asd   '.trim()
"asd"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the `trim()` function [PHP Manual - Trim](http://php.net/trim)

```
$str = ' Hello World ';
echo trim($str);

// will result in "helloworld"
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the trim function such as:

```
$myString = ' The string to trim ';
$myString = trim($myString);

echo $myString;
```

The output of this is: 'The string to trim'

Notice the removal of the spaces...